# Golang Facebook Graph API App Engine

Tags: facebook, google-app-engine, facebook-graph-api, go

I'm using huandu/facebook for Golang to access the FB API. https://github.com/huandu/facebook

This works really well locally but when I try to run from the Google App Engine environment, I can't get it to run.

I used this code locally:

```
res, err := fb.Get("/me", fb.Params{
        "fields": "id,first_name,last_name,name",
        "access_token": usertoken,
    })
```

In the documentation (link above) they do mention the App Engine environment but I can'f figure out how to ge this to work with the fb.Get convention.

Thanks.

**Edit**

Almost got it to work!:

```
// create a global App var to hold app id and secret.
var globalApp = fb.New("<appId>", "<appSecret>")

session := globalApp.Session(usertoken)  //User token here
context := appengine.NewContext(r)  //Not sure what r should be...
session.HttpClient = urlfetch.Client(context)

res, err := session.Get("/me", nil)

if err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(res); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

If I do this I get back the Id and name. Now all I need to do is request the other parameters. Do I do this in the r parameter to the app engine context?

Comment: What you need to do is well explained in their documents. You need to set your sessions http client to the `appengine/urlfetch` client because the standard `net/http` client will not work there. Simply import that package and put statement equivalent to those in their sample in the appropriate place to make it work. IE you should do this in `init` or some other larger scope so that all requests made by the app are using the reassigned client rather than the standard one. To receive an actual answer you'll need to post a lot more code as this stuff should take place prior to any requests.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal I added code above and almost got it to work. Just need to figure out how to complete the rest of the request parameters.

Comment: What do you mean by 'complete the rest of the request parameters?'

Comment: Please avoid changing the original question once a solution is found. This is called a 'chameleon question' and keeps it from having an accepted answer. Please ask a new question instead. If you've found a solution and your question doesn't have an answer, please post a self-answer so the community can benefit.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the last question asked, the `appengine.NewContext(r)` function takes a [`*http.Request`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request) as a parameter, but this refers to the current request, the one your code is executing in. You can use [`r.URL.Query()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL.Query) if you wanted to get the query parameters that were sent to this request.

If you want to send parameters in another request, like the one to the Facebook API, you can include them directly in the URL you pass to `session.Get()`. You can use [`url.Values.Encode`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Values.Encode) if you want to build a query string from a map of values. If you need to make a request using a method other than GET, such as to an API method that expects JSON, you can use [http.NewRequest](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#NewRequest) eg.

```
session.HttpClient = urlfetch.Client(context)
request, err := http.NewRequest("PUT", url, strings.NewReader("{ "someProperty": 1234 }"))
response, err := session.Do(request)
```